# How to workaround PATCH-request, if PATCH not supported serverside

Tags: rest, paypal, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, http-patch

I'm using ColdFusion 10 to communicate with PayPal's servers and [for some requests](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_update) I'd need to do HTTP PATCH requests which [are not supported by CF10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28689612/982002).

Is the PayPal REST API offering an alternate method to *fake* PATCH requests like appending `?_HttpMethod=PATCH` to the request URI or sending a HTTP Header named `X-HTTP-Method-Override` with value `PATCH`?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to use either Java's `HttpClient` or `curl` and build the PATCH request yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a header named `X-HTTP-Method-Override` with value `PATCH` works with PayPal REST API.